# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in

Tags: php, javascript

all code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sub').click(function() {
        var r = confirm("سلام")
        if (r==true){
        var in_code=document.getElementsByName("code")[0].value;
        var echo="<?php
        include ('conect.php');
        $res2=mysql_query("select * from products where code=".echo('document.write(in_code);');." ");
        $row2=mysql_fetch_array($res2);
        echo $row2['name'];
          ?>" 
        alert(echo);            }
        else {
            document.getElementById("frm1").reset();
            }
```

in this line error:

```
$res2=mysql_query("select * from products where code=".echo('document.write(in_code);');." ");
```

echo('document.write(in_code);'); is not work

how to fix t his or It did better?

Comment: I don't think that code will work. js is client side and php is server side

Comment: Try $sql = "select * from products where code="+in_code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are probably looking for, but you are confusing client side with server side. This script won't work since javascript is client side and php is server side and it will only print/alert as text not parse as php script.

```
var echo="<?php
include 'conect.php';
$res2 = mysql_query(\"select * from products where code='" + in_code + "'\");
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
echo $row2['name'];
?>";
```

To make something like this to work you'll need to use Ajax. Add something like this to your js.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sub').click(function() {
        var r = confirm("سلام")
        if (r==true){
            var in_code=document.getElementsByName("code")[0].value;
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "queryscript.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "html" ,
                data: {inCode: in_code}
                success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        }else{
            document.getElementById("frm1").reset();
        }
    });
});
```

then retrieve data with file queryscript.php:

```
<?php
    include 'conect.php';
    $foo = $_POST['inCode'];
    $res2 = mysql_query("select * from products where code='$foo'");
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
    echo $row2['name'];
?>
```

I haven't tested the code above but it should give you a start.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes

```
var echo="<?php
    include (\'conect.php\');
    $res2=mysql_query(\"select * from products where code=\".echo('document.write(in_code);');.\" \");
    $row2=mysql_fetch_array($res2);
    echo $row2['name'];
      ?>";
```

And add the `;` at the end.

Comment: Escaping the single quotes is optional in the above case.